# how to process multiple arrays on the client side of an ajax call

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

I need to process 5 arrays in an AJAX call but only two are being decoded. I have been trying to debug this for one and a half days and I cannot work out why. I make the AJAX call with the following code

```
function postrates(){
  if(changearray.length>0){
     $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        async:false,
        url:"xml_postdailyrate.php",
        data:{
           'changearray':JSON.stringify(changearray),
           'minarray  ':JSON.stringify(minarray),
           'lockarray ':JSON.stringify(lockarray),
           'costarray ':JSON.stringify(costarray),
           'availarray':JSON.stringify(availarray)
        },
        success:function(JSON){
           changearray=[];
           availarray =[];
           costarray  =[];
           minarray   =[];
           lockarray  =[];
        },
        error:function(){
           alert('Failed');
        }
     })
  }
}
```

It passes the arrays OK, the following server side code has been stripped down to make my testing easier.

```
<?php
   header("Content-Type: application/json");
   $changearray="Empty";
   $availarray="Empty";
   $minarray="Empty";
   $lockarray="Empty";
   $costarray="Empty";
   if(isset($_POST['changearray'])){
      $changearray=json_decode($_POST['changearray']);
   }
   if(isset($_POST['availarray'])){
      $availarray=json_decode($_POST['availarray']);
   }
   if(isset($_POST['minarray'])){
      $minarray=json_decode($_POST['minarray']);
   }
   if(isset($_POST['lockarray'])){
      $lockarray=json_decode($lock);
   }
   if(isset($_POST['costarray'])){
      $costarray=json_decode($_POST['lockarray']);
   }
   $arr['changearray'] =$changearray;
   $arr['availarray'] =$availarray;
   $arr['minarray'] =$minarray;
   $arr['lockarray'] =$lockarray;
   $arr['costarray'] =$costarray;
   $arr = json_encode($arr);
   echo("$arr");
```

Firebug "post" tab displays the 5 arrays correctly as

```
changearray [63291,63368,63292]
minarray    ["7","9","8"]
lockarray   ["X","X","X"]
costarray   ["4","6","5"]
availarray  ["1","3","222"]
```

The Firebug "JSON" tab displays

```
changearray [63291, 63368, 63292]
 0           63291
 1           63368
 2           63292
availarray  ["1", "3", "222"]
 0          "1"
 1          "3"
 2          "222"
minarray    "Empty"
lockarray   "Empty"
costarray   "Empty"
```

I cannot find out why it does not decode minarray, lockarray, costarray.

Thank you for taking the time to read my problem.

Comment: does the order posted have any effect? on the php start with `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: `json_decode($lock);` should be `json_decode($_POST['lockarray']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the key `"minarray"`, you are using the key `"minarray  "` (note the spaces). The same for the other two arrays.

Comment: @Chris I noticed that the comments were not meant for thanks which is the only reason I did not say it but you saved me a lot of time.